# SQL CASE Statement Error while checking conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, case

The scenario is that i have two columns one is **Quantity** and other is **Type**. Now what i am trying to do is check if type is **"rec"** then it take all the values from quantity and add them and if the type is **"issue"** then it will get only those fields whose type is receiving and add them all on the basis of **ITEM ID**. The SQL Query i have written is here:

```
 SELECT f.`Itemm_ID`,ABS(SUM(f.`Quantity`)) AS recieving, TYPE ,
(CASE 
WHEN f.`Type` = 'issue'
THEN ABS(SUM(f.`Quantity`))
END)
FROM stock_journal AS f
WHERE f.`Itemm_ID`='1'
```

Now the thing is everything is working fine except CASE statement which is returning null.
Please help me in resolving my issue. Thank you

Comment: `case` _expresssion_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need in

```
SELECT f.`Itemm_ID`,
       ABS(SUM(f.`Quantity`)) AS recieving, 
       TYPE,
       ABS(SUM(CASE WHEN f.`Type` = 'issue'
                    THEN f.`Quantity`
                    ELSE 0
                    END))
FROM stock_journal AS f
WHERE f.`Itemm_ID`='1'
```

PS. Does `f.Quantity` may be negative? If not then `ABS()` is excess. If it may then `ABS()` must wrap inner `f.Quantity`, not the whole `SUM()`, maybe.

PPS. `TYPE` in output is formally incorrect (contradicts with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`), I'd recommend wrap it with `ANY_VALUE()`.

---

> i didn't get your recommendation of wrapping type with value can you please elaborate more.

I mean that (maybe, I'm not sure) you need

```
SELECT f.`Itemm_ID`,
       SUM(ABS(f.`Quantity`)) AS recieving, 
       TYPE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.`Type` = 'issue'
                THEN ABS(f.`Quantity`)
                ELSE 0
                END)
FROM stock_journal AS f
WHERE f.`Itemm_ID`='1'
```

Comment: quantity can be negative too. 
and i didn't get your recommendation of wrapping type with value can you please elaborate more.

Comment: @smartF Updated.

Comment: got it Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked syntax for `CASE` I think you are missing `ELSE` part in the query

Eg:-

```
SELECT OrderID, Quantity,
CASE
    WHEN Quantity > 30 THEN "The quantity is greater than 30"
    WHEN Quantity = 30 THEN "The quantity is 30"
    ELSE "The quantity is under 30"
END
FROM OrderDetails;
```

check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) for syntax